# javascript engine processing code after submit

Tags: javascript

When I do submit, then call another method immediately:

```
this.getForm().submit();
someJSFunctionCall();   //contains just alert
```

Is the submit blocking? If so How/why is the next method invoked?
Since the page is reloading, why the browser continue processing?

Comment: Yes, unless you call async code like ajax call, code blocks run successively and "block" next one until it finish

Answer (score 1):

You are doing synchronous form submit, so the browser stops all javascript on this page and loads new document by submitting form. You may want serialize form data and make async request and then process the result or whatever.

Comment: So how come someJSFunctionCall is being called?

Comment: either call it _before_ submitting form or you can't use native form.submit functionality and have to serialize your form and make XMLHttpRequest